# Youtube crashes audio

Tags: macos, audio, crash, youtube

Whenever I play videos from youtube, the speakers seem to crash, the sound plays more times even on it and repeats. I can't control my sound settings, but the video continues to play. That sound stops only on forced reboot, creating holes in my ears.

I'm using Google Chrome on Mac OS X 10.8.5

What can I do to fix this? The problem appeared when I uninstalled XVID player (I used the UninstallXVID.app for that)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not about XVid Player actually, but it was the Youtube's experimental HTML5 player. I left the HTML5 test and it was well again.